# Reading information from a .CER file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, certificate

For a colleague's convenience I built a small desktop program that receives as input a *.CER* file and a *.p12* file and transforms them into the proper *.PEM* format that Apple needs for iOS Push Notifications as described in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2011/05/12/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12/).

It actually just executes console commands to convert both files into a single *.PEM* file which lately will be used to sign the Push Notifications.

In my interface I got a `NSTextField` where the user can write the iOS application *Bundle Identifier* since all the generated files will be using it as their name's prefix.

[image: .PEM file generator]

I realized that inside the original *.CER* file we can find the *Bundle Identifier* and I thought: hey, let's use that instead so my friend can't make any mistake.

So my question is if there is anyway at all to parse a *.CER* file in Objective-C in order to obtain the iOS application *Bundle Identifier*.